# Why coffescript produce an extra argument for loop: "menu i + 1, dish for dish, i in courses"

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

```
menu i + 1, dish for dish, i in courses
```

This is one line of sample code at section "Loops and Comprehensions" from coffeescript homepage. And it will produce like below which is also provided at the homepage:

```
for (i = _j = 0, _len1 = courses.length; _j < _len1; i = ++_j) {
  dish = courses[i];
  menu(i + 1, dish);
}
```

The variable _j is not necessary, so the code below works too:

```
for (i = 0, _len1 = courses.length; i < _len1; i++) {
  dish = courses[i];
  menu(i + 1, dish);
}
```

Why _j is produced? Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: That's just how CoffeeScript does it.

Comment: (So, no, you're not wrong)

Comment: Compile `menu dish for dish in courses` and watch the `i` disappear.

Comment: @hpaulj nailed it! With your comment and Bergi's answer, the mystery is solved.

Comment: @hpaulj, yeah, this will make `i` disappear, but `menu` function will only get one parameter like this `menu(dish)`, so seems that I have to keep the `i`.

Comment: It wasn't meant to work with `menu`.  It was just a learning suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why _j is produced?

It allows you to tamper with the `i` variable in the loop body, and resets it to the correct `_j` value after each iteration. CoffeeScript doesn't recognize when you don't, so it cannot omit it even if unnecessary.

> Am I wrong somewhere?

Nope. Just don't care about any underscore-prefixed variable.